# update_option with array_push adding mutiple copies

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-options

A plugin I'm working on checks if an option exists. If it does it will update that option by adding new values to the array. When I `var_dump` the new option value looks great, but when I check the database after calling `update_option` the new value is added multiple times.

Code I'm calling to update the option

```
$this->my_option = get_option( 'option_target' );
$add_to_option   = [
    'id' => 'foo',
    'name' => 'Foo name',
    'values' => [
        [ 'some' => 'value', 'other' => 'value' ],
        [ 'some' => 'value', 'other' => 'value' ],
    ];
];
if ( ! is_array( $this->my_option ) ) {
    // add_option();
} else {
    array_push( $this->my_option, $add_to_option );
    var_dump( $this->my_option ); // this looks correct
    update_option( 'option_target', $this->my_option, 'yes' );
}
```

After I reload the page (plugin settings page), it updates the options table, but instead of having an array of 2 items (which it should have), the array is anywhere from 3-5 items. The first item is the original option setting/value and the others all are `$add_to_option` and I can't understand why.

I should add, for now, this is being called inside `init_settings` function from `add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'init_settings' ), 11 )`

Edit: Including an example of what a `var_dump` would look like before and after.

Before

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '777d0d' (length=6)
      'name' => string 'Default' (length=7)
      'foo' => 
        array (size=22)
          0 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          1 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
```

After

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '777d0d' (length=6)
      'name' => string 'Default' (length=7)
      'foo' => 
        array (size=22)
          0 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          1 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string 'new-prop-1'
      'name' => string 'New Prop'
      'foo' => 
        array (size=10)
          0 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          1 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...

  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string 'new-prop-1'
      'name' => string 'New Prop'
      'foo' => 
        array (size=10)
          0 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          1 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...

  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string 'new-prop-1'
      'name' => string 'New Prop'
      'foo' => 
        array (size=10)
          0 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          1 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
```

Comment: note that storing serialised data like this opens you up to object deserialisation attacks. Also if another plugins object makes its way in there and gets serialised, PHP will fatal error when its deserialised if the plugin is deactivated with a class not found error. It's safer to JSON encode or better yet, use separate options with a naming scheme. Also can you update your question to include examples of before and after updating? It's not clear if you're expecting it to replace existing items or not, and it would be helpful for understanding

Comment: @TomJNowell I can't use a separate option because the consumer of this option is a theme. The ideal situation is that I get the existing option array, append my new properties to it, then save that combined array to the table. I'll update the question with an example showing what a `var_dump` would look like before and after.

Comment: can you expand the code to include a more lines before/after? Is this on a settings page? What conditions trigger the code? If it always runs on `init_settings` then it will run on every page, including 404's/`admin-post.php`/AJAX/REST API/RSS/etc What is the purpose of the option? It may be worth switching to `admin_init` so it doesn't run on non-admin screens, but that still leaves that most settings pages will run through an intermediate such as `admin-post.php` or another file giving 2 chances not 1. If so there's nothing wrong with the code you shared, the problem is elsewhere

Comment: I think the problem was a misunderstanding on my part. I added an id check for the options before running any code. I also moved the code so it wasn't called every time the plugin was loaded (this was probably the root cause of my issue).